# How long does it take to take a photo with a Samsung Gear 360 camera?

Tags: 360-panorama, samsung

How long does it take when you're​ taking a 360 degree photo with this camera? And is this camera just a toy?

Comment: "is this camera just a toy?" That is purely opinion-based. A Ferrari is just a toy for the very wealthy, in the eyes of a person who doesn't care about performance cars. Finger paints are "just a toy" in many people's eyes, but amazing art has been made with them.

Comment: Everything is a toy if you use it for a joy.

Comment: @scottbb I have tried that camera for now (V1.0) and You can take high-quality pictures with that, but it's frustrating slow. If You're going to take only one Picture from some place, then I say buy it. But if You are about to take a multiple pictures, like mapping bigger area to Google Street view, I recommend to bough something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as any other camera.  It's two fish eye lenses mounted back to back.  Take an instantaneous single shot or take a movie. Your choice.

It's a tool if you NEED 360 pictures.  A toy if you don't.  For most people I suspect it's a toy, and quite an expensive one.

Comment: Yes, I had opportunity to try Samsung Gear 360 Camera vol.1, and working with that item were slow and frustrating.